# Where to read theme colors used by gnome-terminal?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

Where can I read the hex or RGB codes for colors used by the gnome-terminal?

Under the terminal Preferences, I see it is using colors from the system theme, but I don't know where to read those. The system theme should be what as installed by default with Ubuntu 18.04.

I understand themes are under /usr/share/themes; but I can't figure out which is the CSS file and the code within it I should be looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 you need to look for gtk themes..

for example if you are using Ambiance as a Applications Theme..

this is the file..
`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-terminal.css`

and some of the contents in it are

```
/* gnome-terminal */
@define-color terminal_bg #300a24;

    vte-terminal.terminal-screen {
        -TerminalScreen-background-darkness: 0.95;
        background-color: @terminal_bg;
        color: #fff;
```

this means the background color of the terminal is defined as terminal_bg `#300a24`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was curious since the colors have changed a bit since the introduction of yaru and particularly with the release of 19.10. I can't find a section like in PRATAP's answer but I manged to find this: https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/gtk/src/default/gtk-3.20/_ubuntu-colors.scss

```
// Terminal colors
$terminal_bg_color: #300A24;
$terminal_base_color: lighten($terminal_bg_color, 5%);
$terminal_fg_color: white;
$terminal_borders_color: darken($terminal_bg_color, 10%);
```