# Ubuntu 22.04 chose themes for the terminal that automatically switch between clear and dark

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome. When I switch between light and dark themes every app switches fine and so it does the terminal, which is nice. However I really dislike the dark violet theme that comes by default with the terminals in Ubuntu, I prefer something more in the line of the Tango Light theme, or similar. I can choose this theme in the settings, but if I do this then it does not change to dark theme automatically when I change the system setup.

Is it possible to chose specifically the colors to use with light and dark mode for the terminal?

PS: Somehow it was working fine yesterday, I really don't know how I made it work, but now it went back to the default violet for light mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Gnome terminal. While the header bar adopts the preference, the terminal doesn't.

The new default terminal of Gnome supports that. You can install that terminal in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install gnome-console`.

Comment: Thank you, with this terminal app it works. This terminal however has zero settings and the colors are not very pleasant to the eye (the night mode even has a slight transparency, why?). Do we know where is the file that defines the default gnome terminal colors? I just want to change the ugly vibrant violet background, which is probably a single color code in some file. I was looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147335/823631) but cannot find such file in my Ubuntu 22.04 Yaru theme.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it answers your current question. Feel free to open an new question to ask about changing colors of gnome-terminal. Answer on your current question is as I indicated: it is not possible to have gnome-terminal automatically switch.